# Changing order of x axis ggplot2 facet wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, facet

I have asked a similar q before but had trouble getting my query across. Here is a full reproducible example. Data as follows:

```
Fact<-structure(list(Code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L), .Label = c("i", "m", "R", "T", "TA", "TB", "TS", "TU", 
"U", "UJ", "UK", "UO", "UY", "UZ", "w", "X", "XHH", "XSW"), class     = "factor"), 
Initials = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AA", "FF", "HH", 
"II", "KJ", "KK", "LD", "LL", "TT", "WY"), class = "factor"), 
FactorName = structure(c(3L, 11L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 10L, 7L, 
5L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 
8L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 
10L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 
7L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 11L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 
3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 3L, 11L, 10L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 8L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 
10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 7L), .Label = c("Exchange Rate Sensitivity", 
"Growth", "Investment Trusts", "Leverage", "Liquidity", "Market Sensitivity", 
"Medium-Term Momentum", "Short-Term Momentum", "Size", "Value", 
"Volatility"), class = "factor"), Rating = c(0.982, 0.471, 
0.532, 0.49, 0.791, 0.235, 0.0159, 0.425, 0.437, 0.642, 0.937, 
0.229, 0.715, 0.537, 0.881, 0.857, 0.687, 0.409, 0.363, 0.567, 
0.328, 0.645, 0.305, 0.826, 0.538, 0.381, 0.726, 0.0473, 
0.884, 0.847, 0.063, 0.278, 0.452, 0.473, 0.981, 0.4, 0.774, 
0.805, 0.982, 0.889, 0.281, 0.288, 0.765, 0.51, 0.784, 0.00634, 
0.293, 0.0331, 0.874, 0.0806, 0.253, 0.295, 0.11, 0.775, 
0.807, 0.164, 0.695, 0.792, 1, 0.57, 0.691, 0.432, 0.252, 
0.318, 0.287, 0.249, 0.997, 0.486, 0.794, 0.228, 0.0345, 
0.295, 0.342, 0.684, 0.346, 0.557, 0.929, 0.89, 0.356, 0.507, 
0.85, 0.353, 0.171, 0.968, 0.915, 0.564, 0.89, 0.00313, 0.39, 
0.274, 0.97, 0.213, 0.0792, 0.549, 0.916, 0.528, 0.248, 0.525, 
0.631, 0.27, 0.0294, 0.221, 0.627, 0.628, 0.666, 0.0401, 
0.784, 0.605, 0.66, 0.602, 0.094, 0.445, 0.389, 0.494, 0.104, 
0.612, 0.834, 0.182, 0.298, 0.464, 0.338, 0.269, 0.843, 0.755, 
0.238, 0.794, 0.266, 0.587, 0.653, 0.873, 0.354, 0.54, 0.451, 
0.863, 0.611, 0.00506, 0.767, 0.477, 0.56, 0.722, 0.125, 
0.667, 0.626, 0.139, 0.364, 0.943, 0.266, 0.223, 0.361, 0.473, 
0.624, 0.167, 0.449, 0.148, 0.334, 0.523, 0.666, 0.503, 0.287, 
0.193, 0.992, 0.468, 0.678, 0.235, 0.221, 0.566, 0.612, 0.00794, 
0.249, 0.329, 0.695, 0.714, 0.236, 0.69, 0.187, 0.721, 0.173, 
0.413, 0.833, 0.984, 0.604, 0.0594, 0.798, 0.684, 0.793, 
0.186, 0.728, 0.923, 0.911, 0.608, 0.634, 0.73, 0.361, 0.0534, 
0.251, 0.871, 0.948, 0.306, 0.483, 0.562, 0.205, 0.0798, 
0.0288, 0.618, 0.784, 0.0358, 0.949, 0.134, 0.141)), .Names = c("Code", 
"Initials", "FactorName", "Rating"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-209L))
```

And I the code for my plot.

```
Exp<-ggplot(Fact)+ aes(x = Code, y = Rating, fill = Initials) + geom_col()
Exp<- Exp+facet_wrap(~FactorName, ncol = 3, drop = TRUE) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) + labs(y="Active Rating") + labs(x="")    
Exp
```

Now the order of the x axis for each facet is alphabetical. Instead I Want to group the initials together so the bar colours are grouped together for each factor name plot. ie all the red are next to each other, blue next to each other etc etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That the order / colour of each bar in each Facet is the same.. for example Code "i" bar would be blue in each factorname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
as.tbl(Fact) %>% 
  arrange(Initials) %>%
  mutate(Code2=factor(Code, levels=unique(Code))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Code2, y = Rating, fill = Initials)) + geom_col()+
        facet_wrap(~FactorName, ncol = 3, drop = TRUE)
```

[image]

The idea is to arrange according `Initials`, then create new factor levels accoring the occurence in the dataframe using `unique`.